# Jest: test component and boolean to display loader

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am learning Jest for testing component and logical stuff.

Here is my component that I would like to test :

```
import {Component, Input} from @angular/core;

@Component({
  selector: "nsnet-bouton-download",
template: `
   <div>
    <nsnet-inline-loader *ngIf="isDocumentLoading"></nsnet-inline-loader>
    <button [ngClass]="{'is-not-loading': !isDocumentLoading}">Download</button>
   </div>
  `
})

export class ButtonDownloadComponent {
  @Input() isPdfLoading: boolean = false;  
}
```

And here is my test that I have wrote so far:

```
import {BoutonTelechargerComponent} from "../../../../main/frontend/common-ng2/component/bouton-telecharger";
import {InlineLoaderComponent} from "../../../../main/frontend/common-ng2/component/loader/inline-loader.component";

describe("Le composant BoutonTelechargerComponent", () => {

  let component: BoutonTelechargerComponent;
  component = new BoutonTelechargerComponent();

  const loader = new InlineLoaderComponent();
  const isPdfLoading = component.isDocumentLoading;



  describe("est bien créé", () => {

    it("sans erreur(s)", () => {
      expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

I would like to know how to test the boolean that display the loader and should I test the ngClass or not ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can directly test the booleans as follows:

```
it("should show the loader", () => {
   // setting up component data 
   expect(component.isDocumentLoading).toBeTrue(); // if its loading
   expect(component.isDocumentLoading).toBeFalse(); // if its false
});
```

You can also check if the component `nsnet-inline-loader` is rendered in the dom by using the `fixture.debugElement`:

```
it("should render nsnet-inline-loader ", () => {
   // setting up component data 
   const ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('nsnet-inline-loader'));
   expect(ele).toBeTruthy(); // if it should be present
   expect(ele).toBeFalsy(); // if it should be absent
});
```

If you want to test if the given class is rendered or not, you can do:

```
it("should renderd button with class", () => {
   // setting up component data 
   const ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.is-not-loading'));
   expect(ele).toBeTruthy(); // if it should be present
   expect(ele).toBeFalsy(); // if it should be absent
});
```

But testing the class is upto your requirements. But if you are to test both the cases it would be a bit redundant.

Also you have `isDocumentLoading` in html and `isPdfLoading`. Should be some sort of mistake and needs to be same.

Comment: we can use toBeTruthy() or toBeFalsy() as well.